# Intersection of two arrays by partial matches

Tags: javascript, arrays

Let's say I have the following arrays:

```
var array_full = ['table', 'sleeping', 'data'];
var array_part = ['sleep', 'able'];
```

Now, I want to filter out items from the array with full strings (`array_full`) if they contain items from the array with partial strings (`array_part`).

I can do it like this:

```
var rez = [];
for (p in array_part) { 
    array_full.filter(function(f) { if (f.indexOf(array_part[p]) > -1) {rez.push(f)} } ) 
}
```

But I'm sure there is a better way, isn't it?

EDIT: Thanks to all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could filter the array and look for part includes with

- [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) for filtering `array_full` with
- [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) for finding a part of `array_part` with
- [`String#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes), a check if a string contains another string.

```js
var array_full = ['table', 'sleeping', 'data'],
    array_part = ['sleep', 'able'],
    result = array_full.filter(s => array_part.some(p => s.includes(p)));

console.log(result);
```

Maintaing the order of `array_part` with a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set), because otherwise you could get mot than one item of `array_full`.

```js
var array_full = ['table', 'sleeping', 'data'],
    array_part = ['sleep', 'able'],
    result = Array.from(array_part.reduce(
        (r, p) => array_full.reduce((q, s) => s.includes(p) ? q.add(s) : q, r),
        new Set
    ));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Sorry for a delayed follow up, but what if I need to filter out those `array_full` items according to the order provided `array_part`? Like, `['sleeping', 'table']`, not `['table', 'sleeping']`. Iterating over the `array_part` list, as done in the post, obviously allows that. But not your otherwise nice oneliner, unfortunately. Any workaround may be? Thanks :)

Comment: it is a bit more complicated. do you have only one matching item?

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by "one matching item"? `array_part` has two items, which partially match items in `array_full`...

Comment: Oh, is it possible that an item from `array_part` matches more than 1 item in `array_full`? Then no, that's not possible.

Comment: ad 2 and in which order do you want then?

Comment: In the same order those partial matches are listed in `array_part`. If `array_part = ['sleep', 'able']`, then the result should be `['sleeping', 'table']`.

Comment: please see edit.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) and [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) like this:

```js
const array_full = ['table', 'sleeping', 'data'];
const array_part = ['sleep', 'able'];

const output = array_full.filter(a => array_part.some(b => a.includes(b)))

console.log(output)
```

`includes` and arrow functions are ES2015+ syntax. If you want ES5, you could do something like this

```js
var array_full = ['table', 'sleeping', 'data'];
var array_part = ['sleep', 'able'];

var output = array_full.filter(function(a) {
  return array_part.some(function(b) {
    return a.indexOf(b) > -1
  })
})

console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 2):

If your use case is really about looking for strings in strings :

you can build a regular expression from `array_part`

Answer (score 2):

```js
var array_full = ['table', 'sleeping', 'data'];
var array_part = ['sleep', 'able'];

var rez = array_full.filter(item => array_part.some(str => item.includes(str)));
console.log(rez);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know the partial words are made of word characters and don't contain characters special to regular expressions like (*, $ . etc...), you could compile `array_part` into a regex:

```js
var array_full = ['table', 'sleeping', 'data'];
var array_part = ['sleep', 'able'];

let rx = new RegExp(array_part.join('|'))
console.log(array_full.filter(w => rx.test(w)))
```

Comment: whis works only if the strings does not contain any special characters of a regular expression.